# windows phone 8 - I want create chat using socket

Tags: c#, node.js, windows-phone-8, socket.io

I use visual studio express 2012, i not unable install  the SocketIO4Net.

```
error:  -  Could not install package 'SocketIO4Net.Client 0.6.26'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Now i am using a [TCP socket client app for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202858(v=vs.105).aspx).

Using this socket above, in my device show connected but in the log of server node nothing happens.

Comment: the link TCP socket client app for Windows Phone 8. not get use.

Comment: now i am using websocket4net, but i can not send message.

Comment: this library websocket4net connect the server, receive message but not send message. - my server is node.js

Comment: the function websocket.send(String message) not work.

Comment: it's over./n github.com/Ayaro/SocketIO4Net.wp7 this library save my life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to do that with NuGet, What you should do is download the files, and add ONE BY ONE to your project, you need a lot of stuff for adding, Then you would use Client.cs for connecting to the server, But still if your server requires cookies and SID, than you have some more stuff to do

Comment: i used the library socketio4net, it helped me a lot

Comment: I was gonna tell you that you need to use socketIO4Net, but you already solved it :)